# Inline height and width on div not applying, while it does on canvas

Tags: html, css

```css
 #mycanvas {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        position : relative;
        top: 100;
        left: 0;
    }
    
    #base_map {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        position : relative;
        top: 100;
        left: 0; 
    }
```

```html
<h1>hello world</h1>
<canvas id="mycanvas" width="850" height="250" style="border: 1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
<div id = "base_map"  width="850" height="250" style="border: 1px solid #000000;"></div>
```

The result is the webpage can show the border of `mycanvas` and `base_map`, but the shape of  `base_map` is not correct.

I don't why since the attributes of canvas and div are the same in the css file.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

While [some HTML elements accept a `width` and `height` as attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_height.asp) (`canvas`, `img`...), others don't (like `div`). You should in the last case use CSS to set those dimensions. Like so:

```css
#mycanvas {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position : relative;
    top: 100;
    left: 0;
}

#base_map {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position : relative;
    top: 100;
    left: 0; 
    width:850px;
    height:250px;
}
```

```html
<h1>hello world</h1>
<canvas id="mycanvas" width="850" height="250" style="border: 1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
<div id = "base_map" style="border: 1px solid #000000;"></div>
```

In your case you are not seeing the `div`'s border, because it doesn't have any height, since it's empty.

Comment: can your code work on ur machine? I tried your code on my machine, sorry to say the result is not improved, same result as shown in the question.

Comment: @Justin it's working, in my computer and also here in Stack Overflow's code snippet. Make sure you don't have a typo.

Comment: @Justind I saw your post below, and it looks like `style.css` is not being included in your HTML. Make sure you are using the correct path in `href`. As you did it means that the HTML and CSS files are in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

hi  i tried your question and you done two mistakes .
first in div you have to write anything like 1 2 or any alphabet .
and second try to give value in pixcel or in percentage no in just 840 0r something .
best of luck.

Comment: could you show your code? I am very rookies to web developement.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by relocating `#base_map { ... }` in `<style>` in `<head>`.

But why ?

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet2" href="style.css" />
<style>
    #base_map {
        margin: 50px 100px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        width:850px;
        height:250px;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>hello world</h1>
    <canvas id="mycanvas" width="850" height="250" style="border: 1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
    <div id = "base_map" style="border: 1px solid #000000;"></div>
</body>
```

The css file only contains:

```
#mycanvas {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position : relative;
    top: 100;
    left: 0;
}
```

The result is shown as below:

[image]